# How to copy specific files from directory into new directory zsh

Tags: linux, zsh, cp

I have a list of file names contained within a text file (a.txt). I want to extract from a directory (b) the files listed in **a.txt** to a new directory (c). The syntax of the filenames in **a.txt** and **b** match. The files in **a.txt** are empty and the files in **b** contain the json message of interest.

For example, the contents of **a.txt** look like:

```
ML3DBHCN___005.json
OCO2_L2_Standard___10r.json
GPM_3IMERGM___06.json
```

and **b**:

```
b/ML3DBHCN___005.json
b/OCO2_L2_Standard___10r.json
b/GPM_3IMERGM___06.json
```

Do i need to write a small .sh file that iterates through **a.txt** and extracts from **b** or can this be completed at once via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the filenames don't contain whitespace or wildcard characters, you can do it as a simple one-liner:

```
cp $(<a.txt) b/
```

If they can contain special characters, you can read them into an array:

```
readarray files <a.txt
cp "${files[@]}" b/
```

Comment: Note that `readarray` is a bash construct and this question is tagged as zsh; in zsh you can use e.g. `IFS=$'\n' files=($(< a)); cp $files /tmp/`.

Comment: @MartinTournoij The tags have been edited since I answered. It said `bash` at the time.

Comment: Oh right, well, having both can't hurt 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move from `b` to `c` the files named in `a.txt` (*and they don't have spaces or wildcards*):

```
(cd /path/to/b && mv $(< /path/to/a.txt) /path/to/c/)
```